# Morphisms between representations of group algebras

Tags: group-theory, category-theory, representation-theory

I am trying to put together a categorical understanding of group representations, and so I would like to understand the equivalence between representations of a group $G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(V)$ and representations of the group algebra $F[G] \rightarrow \operatorname{End}(V)$ as a functor from the category of representations of $G$ to the category or representations of $F[G]$.

The problem is, I'm not sure exactly what the morphisms should be for representations of $F[G]$. I can think of the category of representations of $G$ as the functor category from $B_G$ to $\operatorname{Vect}_F$, where $B_G$ is the one-element category $G$. Then morphisms between representations are natural transformations between functors, and this boils down to the usual definition. For representations of $F[G]$, however, I'm not sure how to see those as a category, because I don't know how to represent $F[G]$ as a category. **Is there a way to see the collection of $F$-algebra homomorphisms from $F[G]$ to $\operatorname{End}(V)$ as a category of functors, similar to the case for representations of $G$?**

Comment: It's easier to just see the category as the left $F[G]-$modules.

Comment: Are you attached to viewing a group $G$ only as the one-object category $B_G$? There's a perfectly good category of $F$-algebras and $F$-algebra modules that you could use, provided that you're happy to non-categorically construct the group algebra $F[G]$

Comment: I'm not necessarily attached to thinking of $G$ as $B_G$. What I'm looking for is more of a method that would lead me to the correct definition of "morphism" of representations of group algebras, in the way that viewing $G$ as $B_G$ leads to the correct definition of morphism between group representations.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - absolutely, the issue is that I'm trying to explain how we turn the problem of studying representations of groups into studying $F[G]$-modules. I'd like to say group representations are equivalent to algebra representations of $F[G]$, which are in turn equivalent to $F[G]$-modules. Ideally, each of these equivalences should be functors, but I'm not sure what the right notion of "morphism" is for representations of $F[G]$ as an $F$-algebra

Comment: I don't understand why you need that intermediary. If you insist on talking about representations of $G$ why can't you figure out how the categorification of $F[G]$-modules is equivalent to that of $G$-modules which, in turn, is equivalent to that of $G$-reps?

Answer (score 1):

For the rest of this post, we fix a field (or more generally a commutative ring) $$.

Instead of just groups, we will consider arbitrary monoids.
To solve the problem at hand, we will consider $$-linear categories.
These will fit into the following table.

| set world | $$-linear world |
| --- | --- |
| sets | vector spaces |
| monoids | algebras |
| categories | $$-linear category |

More explicitly, we will have all the following similarities:

- A monoid is a set $M$ together with a multiplication map $M × M \to M$ that is associative and admits a unit.
  Similarly, an algebra is a vector space $A$ together with a bilinear $A × A \to A$ that is associative and admits a unit.
- Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, we have for every two objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathcal{A}$ the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X, Y)$.
  Similarly, given a $$-linear category $\mathcal{A}$, we have for every two objects $A$ and $B$ a vector space $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)$.
- Given a category $\mathcal{C}$, we have for every object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ the monoid $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$.
  Similarly, given a $$-linear category $\mathcal{A}$, we have for every object $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$ the algebra $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$.
- A monoid is the same as a one-object category.
  Similarly, an algebra is the same as a one-object $$-linear category.
- We can go from the right column to the left column by forgetting the $$-linear structure:
  every vector space has an underlying set, every algebra has an underlying (multiplicative) monoid, and every $$-linear category has an underlying category.
- Conversely, we can also go from the left column to the right column:
  every set $X$ can be linearized into the free vector space $[X]$,
  every monoid $M$ can be linearized into the monoid algebra $[M]$,
  and every category $\mathcal{C}$ can be linearized into the $$-linear category $[\mathcal{C}]$.
  These linearizations satisfy similar universal properties.
- For every set $X$ and vector space $V$, we can consider the vector space of maps from $X$ to $V$.
  Similarly, for every category $\mathcal{C}$ and $$-linear category $\mathcal{A}$, we can consider the $$-linear category of functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{A}$.

## Definition of a $$-linear category

> **Definition.**
> A $$-linear category consists of
>
> - a category $\mathcal{A}$, and
> - for every two objects $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal{A}$ a $$-vector space structure on $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)$,
>
> such that for every three objects $A$, $B$ and $C$ of $\mathcal{A}$ the composition map
> $$
>   \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B) × \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(B, C)
>   \to
>   \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, C) \,,
>   \quad
>   (f, g)
>   \mapsto
>   g ∘ f
>   $$
> is $$-bilinear.

Every $$-linear category has an underlying ordinary category, which comes from forgetting the vector space structure on the morphism sets.
We can therefore say that ‘a $$-linear category is a category’.
Given a specific category $\mathcal{A}$, we can conversely ask if we can make $\mathcal{A}$ into a $$-linear category.
For this, we need to define for every two objects $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal{A}$ a vector space structure on the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)$, in such a way that
\begin{alignat*}{2}
 (g_1 + g_2) ∘ f &= g_1 ∘ f + g_2 ∘ f \,,
 &\quad
 (λ g) ∘ f &= λ (g ∘ f)
 \\
 g ∘ (f_1 + f_2) &= g ∘ f_1 + g ∘ f_2 \,,
 &\quad
 g ∘ (λ f) &= λ (g ∘ f) \,,
\end{alignat*}
whenever these equations make sense.

## Examples and constructions for $$-linear categories

The primordial example of a $$-linear category is the one of $$-vector spaces:

- Let $\mathbf{Vect}$ denote the category of $$-vector spaces.
  Given two $$-vector spaces $V$ and $W$, we learn in linear algebra that “$\mathrm{Hom}_(V, W)$ is again a $$-vector space”.
  This allows us to make $\mathbf{Vect}$ into a $$-linear category.

Many examples of $$-linear categories are in a similar vein:

> **Construction.**
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a category.
> Suppose that every object $A$ of $\mathcal{A}$ has an underlying vector space structure, and that for every two objects $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal{A}$ the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)$ is a linear subspace of $\mathrm{Hom}_(A, B)$.
> By endowing $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)$ with the vector space structure induced from $\mathrm{Hom}_(A, B)$, we can make $\mathcal{A}$ into a $$-linear category.

Let us emphasize two special cases of this general construction:

- For every $$-algebra $A$ we have the category of left $A$-modules, which we shall denote by $\mathbf{Mod}(A)$.
- For every monoid $M$ we have the category of representations of $M$ over $$, which we shall denote by $\mathbf{Rep}(M)$.

Let us also give a non-example of the above construction:

- Let $\mathbf{Alg}$ be the category of $$-algebras.
  Every $$-algebra has an underlying vector space structure.
  But given two $$-algebras $A$ and $B$, the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbf{Alg}}(A, B)$ is not a linear subspace of $\mathrm{Hom}_(A, B)$.

It should also be stressed that in an arbitrary $$-linear category, the objects don’t need to have an underlying vector space structure!
Let us introduce an example for this:
functor categories.

> **Construction.**
> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $$-linear category.
> Let $F$ and $G$ be two functors from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{A}$.
> Given two natural transformations
> $$
>  α, β \colon F \Longrightarrow G
> $$
> and a scalar $λ ∈ $, we can define new natural transformations
> $$
>  α + β, λ α \colon F \Longrightarrow G
> $$
> via the components
> $$
>  (α + β)_X ≔ α_X + β_X
>  \qquad
>  \text{for every $X ∈ \mathcal{C}$}
> $$
> and
> $$
>  (λ α)_X ≔ λ α_X
>  \qquad
>  \text{for every $X ∈ \mathcal{C}$.}
> $$
> The set of natural transformations from $F$ to $G$ becomes a $$-vector space in this way.
> These vector space structures make the functor category $\mathbf{Fun}(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A})$ into a $$-linear category.

One should compare the above construction to a statement from linear algebra:
for a set $X$ and a vector space $V$, the set of maps from $X$ to $V$ can again be made into a vector space via pointwise addition and scalar multiplication of functions.

## Functors between $$-linear categories

> **Definition.**
> Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be two $$-linear categories.
> A functor $F$ from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$ is *$$-linear* if for every two objects $A$ and $B$ the map
> $$
>  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{A}}(A, B)
>  \xrightarrow{\enspace F \enspace}
>  \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{B}}(F(A), F(B))
> $$
> is $$-linear.
> The full subcategory of $\mathbf{Fun}( \mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} )$ whose objects are the $$-linear functors is denoted by $\mathbf{Fun}_ (\mathcal{A}, \mathcal{B} )$.

We can now talk about equivalences and isomorphisms of $$-linear categories.

- Let $M$ be a monoid.
  The category $\mathbf{Rep}(M)$ is isomorphic to the functor category $\mathrm{Fun}( \mathrm{B}_M, \mathbf{Vect} )$ as $$-linear categories.

## One-object $$-linear categories

Given an object $A$ in a $$-linear category $\mathcal{A}$, we can consider $\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{A}}(A)$.
This is a $$-vector space, and together with composition of endomorphisms, it becomes a $$-algebra.

Suppose conversely that $A$ is a $$-algebra.
We can then define a $$-linear category $\mathrm{B}_A$ consisting of a single object $\ast$ with $\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{B}_A}(\ast) = A$.

We can now formulate a linear version of the previous isomorphism $\mathbf{Rep}(M) ≅ \mathbf{Fun}(\mathrm{B}_M, \mathbf{Vect})$.

- Let $A$ be a $$-algebra.
  The category $\mathbf{Mod}(A)$ is isomorphic to the functor category $\mathbf{Fun}_( \mathrm{B}_A, \mathbf{Vect} )$ as $$-linear categories.
  (This is how we can regard the category of representations of $A$ as a functor category:
  by using $$-linear categories and $$-linear functors instead of just ordinary categories and ordinary functors.)

## Linearization of categories

> **Construction.**
> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category.
> We can define a $$-linear category $[\mathcal{C}]$ as follows:
>
> - The objects of $[\mathcal{C}]$ are the objects of $\mathcal{C}$.
> - For every two objects $A$ and $B$ of $\mathcal{C}$, the vector space $\mathrm{Hom}_{[\mathcal{C}]}(A, B)$ is the free vector space on the set $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(A, B)$.
> - The composition of morphism in $[\mathcal{C}]$ is the $$-bilinear extension of the composition of morphisms in $\mathcal{C}$.
>   The $$-linear category $[\mathcal{C}]$ is the *linearization* of $\mathcal{C}$.

Let us make the following observation.

- Let $M$ be a monoid.
  Then $[\mathrm{B}_M] = \mathrm{B}_{[M]}$.

The linearization $[\mathcal{C}]$ has the following universal property:

> **Proposition.**
> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a $$-linear category.
> Every functor from $\mathcal{C}$ to $\mathcal{A}$ extends uniquely to a $$-linear functor from $[\mathcal{C}]$ to $\mathcal{A}$.
> We get an isomorphism of $$-linear categories
> $$
>     \mathbf{Fun}_( [\mathcal{C}], \mathcal{A} )
>     ≅
>     \mathbf{Fun}( \mathcal{C}, \mathcal{A} ) \,.
>   $$

This universal property should be compared to the correspondence between linear maps $[X] \to V$ and maps $X \to V$ for a set $X$ and vector space $V$, and the correspondence between algebra homomorphisms $[M] \to A$ and monoid homomorphisms $M \to A$ for a monoid $M$ and an algebra $A$.

## Consequence

For every monoid $M$ we can now consider the chain of isomorphisms of $$-linear categories
$$
 \mathbf{Rep}(M)
 ≅
 \mathbf{Fun}( \mathrm{B}_M, \mathbf{Vect} )
 ≅
 \mathbf{Fun}_( [\mathrm{B}_M], \mathbf{Vect} )
 =
 \mathbf{Fun}_( \mathrm{B}_{[M]}, \mathbf{Vect} )
 ≅
 \mathbf{Mod}([M]) \,.
$$